# Kill one of the Nokia tags?

Tags: discussion, retagging, brand

Do we need both the [nokia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia) and [nokia-lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia) tags?
At the moment they cover the same phones and I would think that we only need [nokia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags that are too broad or too specific might be bad, so I think we need to go for [nokia-lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia).

Why?

- Questions tagged [nokia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia) can most likely always be retagged to something more specific that actually has meaning to the question, because it's most likely to be about some app or device.
- Tags like [lumia-800](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-800) and [lumia-900](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-900) might be too specific such that questions *and* answers for either could also work for the other tag, in which case [nokia-lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia) or [lumia-series](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-series) might work out better.

Comment: [tag:nokia-lumia] makes sense then. [tag:nokia] is still a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in some cases you will really need a tag for every model if it is necessary but I think if something is specific to one model we will start to have some problems.

Comment: I can agree, but in that case you would be better to ditch [tag:nokia-lumia] and have something like [tag:lumia-800], [tag:lumia-900], etc.

Comment: @row1 What you mean with "ditch"? Sorry my translator didn't work in that word and I don't know it. Is it something like "vanish"?

Comment: To abandon [tag:nokia-lumia] :) If you are interested http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ditch

Comment: @row1 Thanks man.